# Can i call grails controller-action from terminal?

Tags: grails, ubuntu

I want to call an **action** written in a controller page from **terminal** so that application will work without clicking on it normally.

Is it possible? If so how?

I am using *Grails* as a programming language and *Ubuntu* as Operating System.

Comment: you can write a unit test that invokes the controller and run that from the terminal

Comment: I want something done by [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Comment: With curl simply call the url as done in the browser

Comment: I typed:
curl  --location-trusted --user username:password http://customer1.localhost:8080/MyProject/ -k
However,it showed me login page's view only now i want to logged in from that view. Can u please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this task with the help of curl.
 sudo apt-get install curl

curl full_path_of_action
eg:

curl http://example.com:8080/ApplicationName/controllerName/actionName

Comment: It would be appreciated further if you would briefly explain about the link you have posted. Welcome to Stack Overflow.